# CRM 2011 to SharePoint Document Management Settings - You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this operation

Tags: document-library, site-collection, dynamics-crm

I have SharePoint 2010 and Dynamics CRM 2011 for which I am trying to create a Document Management site.

I have installed the CRM list component in SharePoint and activated it from SharePoint Central Administration, this is OK.

I then log into my CRM and go `Settings -> System -> Document Management -> Document Management Settings`.

I add the URL `http://intranet.mydomain.com` and click next, it says the SharePoint site is valid, great so I click next.

I then click next again (I don't organize based on entity).

On the next page it tries to create the document library, which all fail for the following libraries:

```
http://intranet.mydomain.com/account
http://intranet.mydomain.com/kbarticle
http://intranet.mydomain.com/lead
http://intranet.mydomain.com/opportunity
http://intranet.mydomain.com/product
http://intranet.mydomain.com/quote
http://intranet.mydomain.com/salesliterature
```

Under the failure reason it says '**You do not have sufficient permissions  to perform this operation**'.

As an overview I am running SharePoint, CRM and SQL under the following domain service accounts:

**CRM**

```
CRM_Application
CRM_Async
CRM_Deployment
CRM_Sandbox
```

**SharePoint**

```
SP_Farm
SP_PortalAppPool
SP_PowerPivotRefresh
SP_Services
SP_ExcelUser
SP_VisioUser
SP_ProfilesAppPool
SP_CacheSuperReader
SP_CacheSuperUser
```

**SQL**

```
SQL_DatabaseEngine
SQL_PowerPivot
SQL_ReportingService
SQL_ServerAgent
```

Appreciate any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please make sure that you have given the account your using the right permissions to the sharepoint site or it will fail like yours did on creation!

The security is maintained in SharePoint. If the user your using does not have access to documents in SharePoint then they wont have access in CRM as well. If the user your using does have access in sharepoint then it will be the same in CRM ;)

http://www.develop1.net/public/post/CRM-2011-Document-Management.aspx